# (ECONNREFUSED). Proxy error: Could not proxy request /members from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/

Tags: reactjs, node.js, flask

I am new to Flask and React. I am creating this practice website where I have passed a JSON response in the flask server and I want this data to be displayed on the react client.

**server.py** (flask)

```
from flask import Flask
app=Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/members")
def members():
    return{"members":["m1","m2","m3"]}

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**app.js** (react)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {
  const[data, setData]=useState([{}])

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("/members").then(
      res=>res.json()
    ).then(
      data=>{
        setData(data)
      console.log(data)
  }
    )
  },[])

  return (
    <div>Data received :</div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Additionally, I manually added a line in **package.json** file

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:5000"
```

I have been getting the following error:
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /members from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/ (ECONNREFUSED).

"proxy":"http://localhost:5000/" --> adding a slash after the port number
checked by replacing localhost with ip address 127.0.0.1
running the flask and react project simultaneously
running them on different terminals on VScode and seperately on even on windows cmd

I appreciate your guidance and Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my issue was installing CORS package

```
pip install flask_cors
```

and then adding the following lines in server.py

```
from flask_cors import CORS
app=Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

additionally, this is my **package.json**

```
 "proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:5000"
```

and not

```
 "proxy":"http://localhost:5000"
```